# What does 雄于 in 少年雄于地球，则国雄于地球 (from a Liang Qichao quote) mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

As I understand, [梁启超](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A2%81%E5%90%AF%E8%B6%85) (Liáng Qǐchāo) is a famous Chinese patriot, who opposed imperialism and European influence prior to and during World War I.  My teacher mentioned a quote from him (少年强则中国强), so I looked it up and found this:

> 少年强则国强，少年智则国智，少年富则国富，少年独立则国独立，少年自由则国自由，少年进步则国进步，少年胜于欧洲，则国胜于欧洲，少年**雄于**地球，则国**雄于**地球。
>   <sub>梁启超 [(source)](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4%E5%BC%BA/3780413)</sub>

Each part of this quote has a similar structure, e.g., 少年强则国强, which means something along the lines of "strong youth leads to strong country".

However, I don't understand 雄于 in this quote.  I've only ever encountered 雄 previously in 英雄 ("hero").  I didn't find anything meaningful on [YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9B%84%E4%BA%8E) or [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E9%9B%84%E4%BA%8E), so I'd guess 雄于 is particular to this quote.

**Question**: What does 雄于 in 少年雄于地球，则国雄于地球 mean?

Answer (score 2):

雄 as a verb has the meaning of 'be dominant'

少年雄于地球 = (If our) youths are dominant on Earth

则国雄于地球 = Then (our) nation will be dominant on Earth

Answer (score 1):

According to dictionary owned by Ministry of Education in Taiwan.

[雄](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000007477) means:

> 超群的、傑出的。

(Better than a lot of people, outstanding)

And you can think A於 as 比...還A. So in this example, you can think 雄於地球 as 比地球還雄.(It means exceptionally better than that on earth.)

So 少年雄於地球，則國雄於地球 means if young people are exceptionally better than other young people on earth, then nation is exceptionally better than other nations on earth.